# Rearranging table rows through jQuery giving undesired results in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to rearrange the table rows in the preformatted HTML table.The HTML table is being displayed as in the below fiddle.. My total HTML is given in this fiddle.

[Initial Look of the table](http://jsfiddle.net/J7WPb/16/)

I am trying to rearrange the <td> with texts containing texts "One" and "Two".I am identifying those "One" and "Two" rows using "rowspan" attribute. If you see the below fiddle in non IE browser you can have a clear picture on what i am trying to do..

[After rearranging](http://jsfiddle.net/J7WPb/17/)

But the problem is, This Code is working fine in browsers other than IE(I have tested in Chrome and Firefox). I am unable to find where the problem is...

Please help me to correct my code to have cross browser compatibility.

Comment: Do you get any javascript errors on IE? JSLint shows warnings for one of your fiddles.

Comment: @Heikki Could you please identify the problem with my code.. My IE browser is not showing any error. Thanks

Comment: Simply click the "JSLint" button in your second fiddle.

Comment: try rowSpan instead of rowspan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your answers, I found the problem.. IE is assigning the index from 1 to the elements. So giving

```
 find('td.mrGridCategoryText:eq(0)')
```

is giving undesired results, If i change it to 1 then i am getting correct result in IE but not in others.Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J7WPb/23/
  So

```
 i need to give eq(0) if other browsers and eq(1) if IE :-(
```

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, use IE9 (Windows 7+ only) and press "F12" for the console and debugging abilities.

You can then even use the javascript debugger to refresh the page and have it break on javascript errors

Personally, I don't support IE, not till they start supporting the "internet" the way every other "way better browser" does

### UPDATE

I found a problem! When IE8 loads the page there is an error on line 195 of file LayoutCM.js

In other words, I don't think the error is in your code as much as it is a jFiddle issue!
Suffice it to say, IE8 doesn't support "getStyle" on the object it's being called upon (variable "win" expected as "window").
This is just another shining example of IE not supporting the "internet" as I put it earlier.

Hope this information helps!

Comment: older IE(at least 7) you'll need to DL the Developer Toolbar -> http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: +1 for IE not supporting the internet. never heard a truer word.